# Shiny Gridster dynamicly adjust margin sizes

Tags: r, shiny, gridster

I am using the 'Add-on package for using the Gridster library with Shiny', (https://github.com/wch/shiny-gridster), which is downloadable by using the below:

```
devtools::install_github("wch/shiny-gridster")
```

But I would like the size of the gridster items to be able to vary with the a slider in the sidebar.

Any help would be much appreciated.

One other question I have is how do I adjust the css for the gridsterItems so that they have all a different background, e.g. a blue background.

My `ui.R` and `server.R` can be seen below, but the gridster items do not seem to change in size in line with the slider.

First my `ui.R` file

```
# ui.R
library(shinyGridster)
library(shinydashboard)

dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sliderInput("n1", "gridster_box_size:", min = 50, max = 500, value = 300)
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    uiOutput('gg')
)
)
```

and my `server.R` file

```
# sever.R
library(shinyGridster)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  output$myPlot <- renderPlot({plot(1:5)})
  output$myText <- renderText(({'hello test text'}))
  output$gg <- renderUI({

      gridster(width = input$n1, height = input$n1, 
               gridsterItem(col = 1, row = 1, sizex = 1, sizey = 1,
                            sliderInput("n", "Input value:", min = 0, max = 50, value = 10)
               ),
               gridsterItem(col = 2, row = 1, sizex = 1, sizey = 1,
                            textOutput("myText")
               ),
               gridsterItem(col = 1, row = 2, sizex = 2, sizey = 1,
                            plotOutput("myPlot", height = 200)
               )
      )


  })

}
)
```

---

A working version of gridster looks like the below for `ui.R` :

```
# ui.R
library(shinyGridster)
library(shinydashboard)

dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sliderInput("n1", "gridster_box_size:", min = 50, max = 500, value = 300)
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    gridster(width = 300, height = 300, 
             gridsterItem(col = 1, row = 1, sizex = 1, sizey = 1,
                          sliderInput("n", "Input value:", min = 0, max = 50, value = 10)
             ),
             gridsterItem(col = 2, row = 1, sizex = 1, sizey = 1,
                          textOutput("myText")
             ),
             gridsterItem(col = 1, row = 2, sizex = 2, sizey = 1,
                          plotOutput("myPlot", height = 200)
             )
    )
)
)
```

with its complementary `server.R`

```
# sever.R
library(shinyGridster)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  output$myPlot <- renderPlot({plot(1:5)})
  output$myText <- renderText(({'hello test text'}))

}
)
```

Comment: I can't get the `gridsterItems` to run as anticipated. They are just static. Is there something missing from your example to get it working?

Comment: Now edited the question to include a working version....what I am trying to do is to change the way it looks and so I am trying to therefore shift where the rendering is being done, i.e. moved from `ui.R` to `server.R` using `renderUI()` and `uiOutput()`

Comment: The shiny-gridster package was created as a proof-of-concept, and is very old and outdated, so it may not work with recent versions of Shiny. I've updated the README on the project site to reflect that.

Comment: I've got [this](http://jsfiddle.net/h9f63/20/) javascript working when on the **ui**, but I've not managed to get it working when `input$n1` changes yet. @wch - are there any plans to get it fully functional and integrated - would be a great addition.